# Sequelize Associate not found

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a project I'm trying to use sequelize on. It creates the database and tables fine, but it never finds the associate class method, so it never calls the associate method.

This code works fine to create the tables (using the import method) but the Object.keys(db) iterates over each model, but it never finds the associate method.

```
fs.readdirSync('./models')
    .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js') && (file.indexOf('.js') > 0) && (file.indexOf('relations.js') !== 0 );
    })


    .forEach(function (file) {
        var model = sequelize.import('../models/' + file);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
            db[modelName].associate(db);
            console.log('true');
        }
        else {
            console.log('false');

        }
    }
);
```

Class Code Example:

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

```
let userModel = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        },
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            let createdByoptions = {
                foreignKey: 'createdByUserID'
            };
            let emailOptions = {
                foreignKey: 'emailAddressID'
            };

            userModel.hasOne(models.user, createdByoptions);
            userModel.hasOne(models.email, emailOptions)

            //userModel.hasMany(models.tenant, {foreignKey: 'id'});

        },
        addUser: function (identityID) {
            userModel.create({identityUserID: identityID});
        }
    }
});


return userModel;
```

};

Comment: What version of sequelize are you on

Comment: You would also need to to use `as` since you are associating user with itself

Comment: I'm using 4.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequelize has changed how associations and instance methods are defined, post version >4.

So Associations earlier defined as (for version <4)

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
...
}, {
classMethods: {
    associate: function (model) {...}
},
instanceMethods: {
    someMethod: function () { ...}
}
});
```

Should now be defined as

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
...
});

// Class Method
Model.belongsTo(SomeOtherModel);
```

Check the [upgrade guide](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) and [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

Comment: Is it really necessary to import the model *SomeOtherModel* to relate to *Model* ?

Comment: You don’t have to import someOtherModel

Comment: Just do model.someOtherModel