# Sequelize Error: ModelA is not associated to modelB with hasMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three models defined in the following way:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    tableName: 'user',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.User.hasMany(models.RestaurantUser, {
          foreignKey: 'userId'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Restaurant = sequelize.define('Restaurant', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    address: DataTypes.STRING,
    city: DataTypes.STRING,
    zipcode: DataTypes.STRING,
    country: DataTypes.STRING,
    latitude: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    longitude: DataTypes.FLOAT
  }, {
    tableName: 'restaurant',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.Restaurant.hasMany(models.RestaurantUser, {
          foreignKey: 'restaurantId'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return Restaurant;
};
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var RestaurantUser = sequelize.define('RestaurantUser', {
    restaurantId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    tableName: 'restaurantuser',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.RestaurantUser.belongsTo(models.User);
        models.RestaurantUser.belongsTo(models.Restaurant);
      }
    }
  });
  return RestaurantUser;
};
```

When I try to find all restaurants from a user, I do the following query but it throws the error:

> ERROR : { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Restaurant is not associated to
>   RestaurantUser!

The query I do is :

```
return models.RestaurantUser.findAll({
  where: {
    userId: id,
  },
  include: [{ model: models.Restaurant }],
})
.then(restaurants => res.status(200).send(restaurants))
.catch(err => {
  logger.error(err, 'restaurant_get_error');
});
```

Comment: If you are using sequelize > version 4.
The way associations are defined has been changed.

Comment: Ok, I'm using v4. How are they defined now ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938556/sequelize-associate-not-found/44962418#44962418)