# Problem adding allowNull in the foreignKey association 1:1 in the models with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i am doing a simple project with node.js using Sequelize with MySQL database. I was modeling my models associations. One got the hasMany and the other the belongsTo, I set the informations in both(like, as:...,foreignKey:...,onDelete:...), and set in foreignKey the propertie allowNull. When I save de model with the belongsTo method passing the in the request body the foreignKey it saves properly. But when I do this with model that uses in association the method hasOne it doesn't work. It passes that I need to specify the model ID that uses the belongsTo method.

```js
const connection = require('../../config/database');
const DataTypes = require('sequelize').DataTypes;

const Course = connection.define('course', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    courseName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'course_name',
        allowNull: false
    }
},
    { timestamps: false });
Course.associate = models => {
    Course.belongsTo(models.Lecturer, {
        foreignKey: {
            field: 'lecturer_id',
            allowNull: false
        },
        as: 'lecturer'
    });
    Course.belongsToMany(models.Student, {
        through: 'student_course',
        as: 'students',
        foreignKey: 'curse_id',
        otherKey: 'student_id'
    })
}

module.exports = Course;

const connection = require('../../config/database');
const DataTypes = require('sequelize').DataTypes;

const Lecturer = connection.define('lecturer', {
    lecturerName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        field: 'lecturer_name',
        allowNull: false
    }
},
    { timestamps: false });
Lecturer.associate = models => {
    Lecturer.hasOne(models.Course, {
        foreignKey: {
            field: 'lecturer_id',
            allowNull: false
        },
        as: 'course'
    })
}

module.exports = Lecturer;
```

Result:
[ ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'course.courseId cannot be null',
       type: 'notNull Violation',
       path: 'courseId',
       value: null,
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [Object],
       validatorKey: 'is_null',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] } ]

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938556/sequelize-associate-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but it looks like the error shows a camel-case column name (courseId) as opposed to a snake-case column name (course_id).

Also, you have misspelled "course_id" in your `Course.belongsToMany` association.